# Right to Left Panorama control on Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, arabic, hebrew, right-to-left, panorama-control

Is there a way to make the panorama item on Windows phone, right to left? I want to make Hebrew and Arabic apps, with the nice panoramic effect.

I was thinking of manipulating the last PanoramaItem to be loaded first in the MainPage.Loaded but it wont let me as the Panorama.SelectedIndex is read only.

Update: I've tried Panorama.DefaultItem, but it changes the order of the panorama items, and misses the whole thing.

I also need a way to make the alignment of the Title of the panorama, right to left

Comment: You could use <Panorama.HeaderTemplate><Image Source="myheader.png"/></Panorama.HeaderTemplate> and use a transparent png as your header, and just use an image instead of text.

Comment: That's a good idea, ill try that, but first i need to fix the right to left thingy for the panorama items.

Comment: I don't understand that part of your question. Can't you just swipe left?

Comment: Yeah, but when you swipe from right to left, the image starts over to its right edge. Try any panoramic windows phone app with a background, and swipe right to left, and you will get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Phone 7 does not yet have full RTL language support. sorry :(

The panorama does allow setting the DefaultItem, rahter than the SelectedItem, but this does affect the way that the background image is rendered. Use this with care.

Comment: thanks Matt, but i've already said, the defaultitem changes the order of the items. I need something to just set the selected one instead of changing their order.

Comment: there isn't a way to programmatically set the selecteditem. The defaultitem doesn't change the order, it changes the relative order in relation to the background.

Comment: poteto potato lol jk. I think I just have to wait then, thanks for your help matt :)